# "Alaska Airlines", "American Airlines", "United Airlines", etc. Why airlines and not airline?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Looking at airline names such as "Alaska Airlines", "American Airlines", "United Airlines" made me wonder: why airlines and not airline, since an airline is defined as "an organization providing a regular public service of air transportation on one or more routes" according to Oxford  Languages. E.g., why not "Alaska Airline"? I don't recall seeing any company using airline in their company name.

Comment: Because these **airline companies** have more than one flight/destination? One direct route (a line) to New York, one to Dallas, one to South Carolina etc.? https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/airline#:~:text=air%C2%B7%E2%80%8Bline%20%CB%88er%2D%CB%8Cl%C4%ABn,routes%2C%20operating%20personnel%2C%20and%20management

Comment: @Mari-LouA, on the other hand we speak of Lufthansa (say) as an airline (singular).

Comment: Each company mentioned in the OP is an airline but Lufthansa doesn't have the word *arline/s* in their name. AIRFRANCE doesn't have *airline* in its name, probably because like Lufthansa it is not a US airline.

Comment: If each company I mentioned is an airline, why the plural in their company names?

Comment: I previously mentioned that each airline offered more than one route (airline) ergo *airlines* (routes). The term airline, meaning air transportation, is not going to exist prior the 1930s-40s, so the Ngram plotting *airline*  peaking in the 1980s shows the frequency of usage. Why does that support the answer [company] airline vs [company]airlines?

Comment: @Mari-LouA thanks, "The term airline, meaning air transportation, is not going to exist prior the 1930s-40s" would be good answer. I updated the plot.

Comment: There is also just air: Ryanair.

Answer (score 1):

Reddit user [anon-honeybee](https://www.reddit.com/user/anon-honeybee) [pointed](https://www.reddit.com/r/EnglishLearning/comments/11cnct7/alaska_airlines_american_airlines_united_airlines/ja3y8y6?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share&context=3) me to [community.infiniteflight.com](https://community.infiniteflight.com/t/why-are-airline-names-plural-e-g-why-is-american-airlines-not-called-american-airline/174997/16), where anon31652286 provided the following answer:

> Well “airline” has become a normal term for us to use now. When airlines were founded, using “airlines” and “airways” would have been more related to the routes the carrier flies. Hence some airlines were called “Air Lines”.

[books.google.com/ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=airline%2Cair+line%2Cairlines%2Cair+lines&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) indicates that the term airline was rather new when these companies were created, and the term "air line" is  older:

[image]